# Does anyone know how to get rid of this space when i press enter after a title in Word?

Tags: microsoft-word

So Im doing an assignment for school, and i have the titles numbered and stuff.. and well, after i press enter after one of the headings it creates HUGE space between it and the heading under it, like it puts the rest of the text on the next page. i tried everything and cant change it. Any tips?
[image]

Comment: I see the cursor right below 1.1. Is that not where the text should go? if not, can you edit the screenshot and show where the next text lands? or do you mean the space between 1. and 1.1?

Answer (score 1):

The spacing is set to a higher value than you like, either the "spacing before" for the Heading 1, or the "spacing after" for the Heading 1.1.

Select one of the headings by clicking on the left margin at the level of the heading. Once the heading is selected, right click on it and select Paragraph... a.

A window opens where you can define all kinds of parameters for that type of heading. Among those there is spacing before/after.

Experiment with those values, but check first where the problem is. It may also be that it is a sum of two values, a bit too much spacing after for Heading 1 combined with too much spacing before for Heading 1.1. I personally normally use only spacing after.
To my eye, the spacing in your example looks fine, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is the space between your title and your first heading, it is the space before or space after formatting of the two paragraphs.

If the problem is that your next paragraph is on the next page, that has to do with the paragraph formatting of the text on that page. Look for "Keep with Next" and "Keep Lines Together" formatting.